# Equation for Determining if a Point Affects a Voronoi Diagram

Tags: voronoi-diagram

Currently I am working on a Javascript program that plots a Voronoi diagram and am trying to find all of the points that form the points that form the region around a point. To make this clearer, here is an example of a potential scenario:

[image: Image of graph]

Point D affects the region around point A if the mid-segment of these points intersects rays cast from the intersection of the mid-segments of points B and C. To break this down, here's what I'm saying in relation to the previous diagram:

[image: Edited image of graph]

Using rough approximations of the mid-segments, D does not intersect the Voronoi boundaries of point A. Using A as the current point, B and C as points known to affect the region, and D as the point checked for it's effect on the region; and knowing the angles and distances of B, C, and D relative to the first point, how can I find if D has an effect on the region?

Answer (score 1):

The [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Relationship_with_the_Voronoi_diagram) is the [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) of the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). Two points have adjacent Voronoi regions if and only if they are connected by an edge in the Delaunay triangulation [[1]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s15/LectureNotes/lecture17/voronoi.pdf). Thus it suffices to [compute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Algorithms) the Delaunay triangulation.

See also [Is it possible to compute only the adjacencies of Voronoi cells in the Voronoi diagram efficiently?](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/soft/polyfaq/node33.html), which describes a [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) approach.